# jQuery count each first li element with class name

Tags: jquery

I wanna count each first li element with class names, here is my code:

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li><a class="active" index="0" href="#">selector1</a></li>
    <li><a class="" index="1" href="#">selector1</a></li>
    <li><a class="" index="2" href="#">selector1</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><a class="" index="0" href="#">selector1</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" index="1" href="#">selector1</a></li>
    <li><a class="" index="2" href="#">selector1</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><a class="active" index="0" href="#">selector1</a></li>
    <li><a class="" index="1" href="#">selector1</a></li>
    <li><a class="" index="2" href="#">selector1</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

js:

```
var countz = $('div ul').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('.active:first').length; }).length;

alert(countz);
```

but my result shows 3. It should be 2 according to this html any ideas ? thanks!

here fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tf7g8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
var countz = $('div>ul>li:first-child>.active').length;

alert(countz);
```

Which just counts all `a` tags that have the class `active` and are a child of `li` elements that are the themselves a first child.  Seems simpler.

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/GRcpL/2/

Answer (score 0):

This'll do the trick:

```
var countz = 0;
$('div ul li:first').find('a').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("active"))
        countz++;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonnysooter/Tf7g8/2/

Answer (score 0):

I would do it that way.

```
var countz = $('div ul').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('li:first').has('.active').length;
}).length;

alert(countz);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use `Size()` with `nth-child()` (if using **jQuery v1.7** or **below**)

```
var active_li_count = $('li:nth-child(1) .active').size();
alert(active_li_count);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cQKhv/

> Note: The .size() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Use the
>   .length property instead.